# React form file upload: Header image not saved in form submission

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express

I am using MERN stack. I make  a blogSchema with headerImage field.For save image in database I use multer in server side. when I post blog by postman. every field including headerImage save in mongodb.
but when I try to post from react. all other fields saved in mongodb but headerImage not save.

my react form code is

```
import {useEffect} from "react";
import AdminMenu from "../../adminManu/AdminManu";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { createBlogAction } from "../../../redux/actions/blogAction";
import toast from "react-hot-toast";


const CreateBlog = () => {

 const { user } = useSelector((state) => state.loginUser) || {}

 const dispatch=useDispatch();
 const handleSubmit = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();

   const data = new FormData(e.currentTarget)

const actualData = {
  user_id: user.data._id,
  title: data.get("title"),
  content: data.get("content"),
  headerImage: data.get("headerImage"), // Add this line
}
console.log(actualData)

dispatch(createBlogAction(actualData))
toast.success("added successfuly")
};
  const blog = useSelector((state) => state.newBlog);
  console.log(blog.blogs)
  useEffect(()=>{

 },[blog])

return (
<div className="container-fluid dashboard">
  <div className="row">
    <AdminMenu />

    <div className="col-md-9 mt-5 mx-auto">

      <div className="tripForm">
      <h3>Add New Blog</h3>

      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}   encType="multipart/form-data">
        
        <div className="form-group">
          <label>Title</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            className="form-control"
            name="title"
         
            required
          />
        </div>

        <div className="form-group">
          <label>Header Image</label>
          <input
            type="file"
            className="form-control"
            name="headerImage"
         
            required
          />
        </div>
      
        <div className="form-group">
          <label>Description</label>
          <textarea
            className="form-control"
            name="content"
            
          ></textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" className=" formButton">
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
 );
```

};

export default CreateBlog;

my controler is

```
exports.addPost=async(req,res)=>{
try {
    const { user_id, title, content } = req.body;
    const headerImage = req.file ? req.file.path : undefined;

    const post = new BlogPost({
      user_id,
      title,
      content,
      headerImage,
    });

    const newPost = await post.save();
    res.status(200).json({ type: "success", data: newPost });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ type: "error", message: error.message });
  }
```

};

router code is

```
const multer = require('multer')
const path =require('path')

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'uploads/');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + '-' + Math.round(Math.random() * 1e9);
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + uniqueSuffix);
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

const router = express.Router();

router.post('/add', upload.single('headerImage'), addPost);
```

in post man every field save in database. but in react from only headerImage not saved. Other fields saved.

Comment: You need to debug it first and provide the debugging details. We will not debug it for you. " not saved" is not a debugging details